# Не подгружаются static файлы css/js в spring boot + security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

Никак не могу добавить css к моему проекту, перепробовал наверное все варианты которые нашёл, не помогло.
При попытке добавить css в браузере у меня стили не загружаются, файл стилей видит, но там почему-то html.

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/registration", "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
}


@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/fonts/**",
            "/images/**"
    );
}
```

}

**MvcConfig**

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}
```

}

В html файле css добавляю так: `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}">`
Пробовал разные пути, не в этом дело.

Путь к сss такой: src/main/resources/static/css/main.css
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузере ошибок нет [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему-то вместо css он отображает html. Вообще не пойму почему и как... Но в файле css он отображает html[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на github : https://github.com/zvuk331/MoneyApp